# How to get notification when external monitor plug in for MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to get notification when external display/monitor plug in.Which API should i use.

I have tried `NSScreen.screens`, and use timer to get screen info array every second. The problem it leads to high cpu usage.

```
    NSScreen.screens
```

Comment: The array should not be cached. Screens can be added, removed, or dynamically reconfigured at any time. When the display configuration is changed, the default notification center sends a `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification` notification. Have you tried observing this notification?

Answer (score 0):

Observing NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification is the answer to this.